# Download pdf file on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, .htaccess

I have this form from zoho crm:

```
    <div id='crmWebToEntityForm' align='center'>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV ='content-type' CONTENT='text/html;charset = UTF-8'>
        <form action='http://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm' name=WebToLeads1041232000000749005 method='POST' onSubmit='javascript:document.charset="UTF-8"; return checkMandatery()' accept-charset='UTF-8'>  
            <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xnQsjsdp' value='fbc5a29ead008c324c3a5bad0887e5bf1f95d083f11d4251a6f8aa5a236fd104'/> 
            <input type='hidden' name='zc_gad' id='zc_gad' value=''/>
            <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xmIwtLD' value='eecaf957dfe7083c05ed797b5ed94512300831df6a467c5c0dca55e1967f2eae'/> 
            <input type='text'  style='display:none;' name='actionType' value='TGVhZHM='/>
            <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='returnURL' value='http://www.example.com/sucess-page' /> 
            <br>

            <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding='6' width=600 style='background-color:white;color:black'>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2' align='left' style='color:black;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;'><strong>After Radical</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap='nowrap' align='left'  style='font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;'>Nombre </td><td style='width:250px;' ><input type='text' style='width:250px;'  maxlength='40' name='First Name' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2' align='center' style='padding-top: 15px;' >
                        <input style='font-size:12px;color:black' type='submit'  value='Submit' /> 
                        <input type='reset'  style='font-size:12px;color:black' value='Reset' /> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

What I want to achieve is that on submit, the user downloads a PDF on the same page. I need this to avoid going to other page and let them copy the URL to download the file without using/sending the form.

The actual behavior of the form is on submit sends the user to `http://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm` and the loads back the page `http://www.example.com/sucess-page` which is in a input value. This page is different from where the user sents the form.

I've tried changing this:

`form action='http://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm`

to this:

`form action='http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf`

It works downloading the PDF on same page (I previously added this to htaccess: `AddType application/octet-stream .pdf`) but then the form doesn't send the user info to the zoho crm management.

Any idea how to achieve this? Maybe jQuery alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Post the form to the same page. Then in your PHP code, check if the form has been submitted. If it has, POST the same data to the crm page using cURL and then echo the PDF link.

Example:

```
<form method="post" action="?">
   ...
</form>
```

And then to check if the form has been submitted...

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     curlPostFunction();
     echo "<a href='http://example.com/example.pdf'>Click to download</a>";
}
```

Read this link for more info on how to create a function to POST using cURL: [cURL Post](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post)

Note that this is just a basic example -- your code should include more checks based on how secure you want your implementation to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting this error after the form is submitted and page loads: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curlPostFunction()` Also I don't need to secure a lot this file.

Comment: curlPostFunction() was just an example I included as I don't have time to write out an entire function for you. You need to create an actual function yourself to POST the data. Please check the link I included on how to do this.